# Does amzon congnito support for authenticating for IAM user

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

There is a basic inquiry, I just suppose I am a Mobile Game vendors, And I have some game player(users). I want to confirm whether the game player will be the IAM User ? If so, how to authenticate the IAM user by using Amazon congnito ? Document is not mention it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to login/authenticate (verify passwords) for AWS IAM users. Amazon Cognito allows you to authenticate your players/users when they login with Facebook, Twitter, Digits, Amazon, Google or any OpenID Connect compatible provider (see [External Identity Providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/) in the documentation). Alternatively, if you store your users and their credentials in your own backend database, you can use Cognito's Developer Authenticated Identities feature to authenticate your players ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/), [sample](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en)).

Whether using an external provider or Developer Authenticated Identities, Cognito enables you to provide your users AWS Credentials so that they can directly access your resources in AWS (e.g. such as S3 or DynamoDB).

Comment: Hi, Scott, thx your pointing, it is clear. I will follow yours go in depth